# Is it acceptable to have multiple aggregation that can theoretically be inconsistent?

Tags: oop, data-modeling

I have a question about the modelling of classes and the underlying database design.

Simply put, the situation is as follows: at the moment we have **Positions** and **Accounts** objects and tables and the relationship between them is that a Position 'has an' Account (an Account can have multiple Positions). This is simple aggregation and is handled in the DB by the Position table holding an Account ID as a foreign key.

We now need to extend this 'downwards' with **Trades** and **Portfolios**. One or more Trades make up a Position (but a Trade is not a Position in itself) and one or more Portfolios make up an Account (but a Portfolio is not an Account in itself). Trades are associated with Portfolios just like Positions are associated with Accounts ('has a'). Note that it is still possible to have a Position without Trades and an Account without Portfolios (i.e. it is not mandatory to have all the existing objects broken down in subcomponents).

My first idea was to go simply for the following (the first two classes already exist):

```
class Account;
class Position {
  Account account;
}
class Portfolio {
  Account account;
}
class Trade {
  Position position;
  Portfolio portfolio;
}
```

I think the (potential) problem is clear: starting from Trade, you might end up in different Accounts depending if you take the Position route or the Portfolio route. Of course this is never supposed to happen and the code that creates and stores the objects should never be able create such an inconsistency. I wonder though whether the fact that it is theoretically possible to have an inconsistent database implies a flawed design?

Looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: I don't think that it implies a flawed design by itself. In the end it comes down to your business logic to avoid taking a consistent state and turning it into an inconsistent one. The only way around this I can see right now would be to group portfolio and position so you could use a single reference in trade.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Dan. While grouping Position and Portfolio is theoretically a solution, in practice it wouldn't fit the requirements very well (they really are completely different concepts so they should have different classes). I guess we could go forward with my proposed design and just make sure the business logic avoids inconsistencies.

Comment: You could also introduce tests into the constructor of Trade which makes sure that the provided position and portfolio have the same parent account and as such make sure the inconsistency is at least caught when produced. Of course the test would also have to be applied each time one of those fields changes.

Comment: If objects become a mess, maybe whole design is flawed? I would agree with Dan, while constructing Trade, add assertion/test code, and throw exception/whatnot if data is not consistent and expose appropriate API to be consumed. For example if Trade could expose correct Accounts directly, not through Trade.Position.Account; Position from Trade could be exposed through ITradePosition interface, which does not exposes Account, etc. - that is, have references in objects but be careful what you expose - only what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The design is not flawed just because there are two ways to get from class *A* to class *D*, one way over *B* and one over *C*. Such "squares" will appear often in OOP class models, sometimes not so obvious, especially if more classes lie in the paths. But as Dan mentioned, always the business semantics determine if such a square must commute or not (in the mathematic sense).

Personally I draw a `=` sign inside such a square in the UML diagram to indicate that it must commute. Also I note the precise formula in an UML comment, in my example it would be

> For every object `a` of class `A`: `a.B.D = a.C.D`

If such a predicate holds, then you have basically two options:

- Trust all programmers to not break the rule in any code, since it is very well documented
- Implement some error handling (like Dan and algirdas mentioned) or, if you don't want to have such code in your model, create a Checker controller, which checks all conditions in a given model instance.